# List affected by keyboard size

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am displaying an `HTML` list with `phonegap` on mobile devices. while the keybord is on I display dynamic list but after the keyborad is down the list is showen only on the top area without the size of the keybord, **list(height)-keyboard(height).**

any ideas?

Comment: Which mobile device? Although html is technically cross platform, getting details like keyboard behaviour right isn't. Also, are you using jquery mobile?

Comment: The problematic device is HTC. You right about cross platform, but it's true for 80%,a lot of stuff works and acts differently on different devices. Yes i'm using jquery mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same Problem on a Galaxy Nexus 4.0.4. On Galaxy S2 with 4.1 its working fine.
I thought about trying android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". But the Problem with this Solution is, that the Keyboard covers some Content.